# HowTo: Find all references to a Field in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class A {
  static public String a;
}

class B {
  public function referToFieldInClassA() {
    System.out.println(A.a);
  }
}
```

Is there anything in the Java reflection APIs to allow me to find all places where a particular field is referenced? What I'm looking for is a way to find out that (given the example) class B has a reference to A.a.

I know I can get all the Fields in a Class via the reflection API. But now I want to find all references to that Field.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried your IDE, or do you really want this information at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

From the standard APIs, I think the answer is no.  Eclipse can do it, but that's not at runtime.

For an incredibly hack-ish way of doing it, get the ClassLoader object, get the resourceAsStream to get something, use something like [JODE](http://jode.sourceforge.net/) to decompile it, and parse the source from inside of the program.

But that's a crazy amount of work.  What the heck are you using this for?

Comment: I suspect its because he wants to encapsulate a field by changing direct access to getters / setters without realizing that most IDE's will do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm actually way beyond what the IDE can do for me. I'm building a dependency graph of my application and storing it in a relational database so that the dependencies can be analyzed offline. So, it would be like taking what the IDE does for me and save the output to a database. I used Dependency Finder to give me all method dependencies quite nicely. Now I'm looking for a clean way to do fields as well. Dependency Finder can do it, as long as the fields aren't final. So that's what I think I'll end up doing. Thanks for the comments though.

Answer (score 1):

If your need is compile-time rather than run-time, and you don't have an IDE, the very old trick of changing the names of the fields and recompiling, and searching for what fails to compile. ;]

Then, of course, get yourself an IDE.